# Promises in AsyncStorage from React Native

Tags: android, ios, promise, react-native

Wrinting a lttle wrapper around AsyncStorage from React Native, i have a little problem with the getAllKeys function.

What is wrong in this snipped, if i want retrive all the values?

```
getAll: function(){
    var items = ["hh"];
    AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
        .then( ks => {
            ks.forEach( k => {
            AsyncStorage.getItem(k)
                .then( v => items.push(v)); //console.log(k, v));
        });
        });
        return items;
  },
```

Thanks very much

Comment: On a side note, using `AsyncStorage.multiGet` is better than using `getItem` for each item

Answer (score 2):

You are returning `items` synchronously, however `.getAllKeys` and `.getItems` return Promises, so are highly likely to be asynchronous

Using `Promise.all` to *wait* for all `AsyncStorage.getItem` to complete, your code can be written as follows

```
getAll: () => 
    Promise.all(AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
        .then(ks => 
            ks.map(k => 
                AsyncStorage.getItem(k)
            )
        )
    )
,
```

usage:

```
.getAll()
.then(items => 
    // do something with items 
)
.catch(err => 
    // handle errors
);
```

to explain the error in the comment - if you use `{}` in an arrow function, you must use `return` to return a value

```
getAll: () => Promise.all(AsyncStorage.getAllKeys().then(ks => {
    console.log(ks);
    // return here
    return ks.map(k => { 
        console.log(k);
        // return here
        return AsyncStorage.getItem(k);
    })
})),
```

Comment: <!-- language: lang-js -->  
   getAll: () => 
    Promise.all(AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
        .then(ks => {
            console.log(ks);
            ks.map(k => {
             console.log(k);
                AsyncStorage.getItem(k)
              }
            )
          }
        )
    ),

trace: ["7", "3", "4", "5", "1", "a", "6", "2"], and 7,3...are the keys
but, just recive a empty array
<!-- language: lang-js -->  
    Storage.getAll()
   .then(items => 
     // do something with items 
     console.log(items)
   )
   .catch(err => 
     // handle errors
     console.log(err)
   );

Comment: Sorry for the above message.
just to say, that i recive a empty array, but there are objects save in the AsyncStorage.

thanks

Comment: because you're using {} in an arrow function , you need to `return ks.map ...` and `return AsyncStorage.getItem(k)` ... I'll edit the answer to show you

Answer (score 1):

You need to :

- form an array of the promises returned by `AsyncStorage getItem(k)`,
- use `Parse.Promise.when()` (or `Promise.all()`) to  aggregate the array of promises,
- return a promise from `getAll()`.

```
getAll: function() {
    var items = ["hh"];
    return AsyncStorage.getAllKeys().then(ks => {
        return Parse.Promise.when(ks.map(k => AsyncStorage.getItem(k))).then(results => items.concat(results));
    });
},
```

If "hh" is just there for debug purposes, simplify to :

```
getAll: function() {
    return AsyncStorage.getAllKeys().then(ks => {
        return Parse.Promise.when(ks.map(k => AsyncStorage.getItem(k)));
    });
},
```

In either case, call as follows :

```
foo.getAll().then(function(results) {
    // here, `results` is an array of values promised by multiple calls to `AsyncStorage.getItem(k)`
    console.log(results);
}, function(error) {
    // here, handle whatever error condition that might have arisen
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Roamer and @Jaromanda. 
I am still understanding how this works. But i dont want retrieve an array of promises, i just want return an array of values of each promise.
how can i achive that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: More explanation needed. `ks.map(...)` returns an array of promises, which is immediately passed to the promise aggregator `Parase.Promise.when()`, which in turn returns a single promise. Therefore the Promise returned by `.getAll()` will, if successful, deliver an array of results. It is totally, 100% unavoidable that these results be delivered by a Promise. Functions involving any sort of asynchronism simply *cannot* return result(s) directly.

Comment: I have added some extra code to the answer to show you how to call `.getAll()` and access the results.